# How to get distinct departments name from Active Directory in Asp .Net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, active-directory

I want to get unique or distinct departments name from AD so what is the correct query for that. Below is my code:

```
private static DomainController GetDomainController(string domainpath)
{
    var domainContext = new DirectoryContext(DirectoryContextType.Domain, domainpath);
    var domain = Domain.GetDomain(domainContext);
    var controller = domain.FindDomainController();
    return controller;
}

private static MyMethod()
{
    var domainController = GetDomainController(ActiveDirectorySettings.DomainPath);

    // Lookup the information in AD
    var ldapEntry = new DirectoryEntry(string.Format("LDAP://{0}", domainController)) { AuthenticationType = AuthenticationTypes.Secure | AuthenticationTypes.FastBind };
    DirectorySearcher ds;

    ds = new DirectorySearcher(ldapEntry)
    {
        SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree,
        Filter = "(&" + "(objectClass=user)" + "(department=" + departmentname + "*))"
    };

    ds.PropertiesToLoad.Add("department");
    if (ds.FindAll().Count >= 1)
    {
        //do something....
    }
}
```

Here I am getting all the departments name including duplicates. But what I want is -

If 3 users belongs to the same department(X) then I want department(X) once not thrice.

Comment: can you please provide the definition of `GetDomainController` function. Currently it is missing from your post.

Comment: which dll or namespace is required to  use `ActiveDirectorySettings.DomainPath`? I'm unable to compile  your code.

Comment: `(ActiveDirectoryConfiguration)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("ldapConfiguration")`

Comment: ohh. That's a setting in your `app.config` or `web.config` file. Is it?

Comment: yes ldap configuration setting is in web.config

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use LINQ to get unique/distinct search results. Here is the code snippet:

```
if (ds.FindAll().Count >= 1)
{
    var overallSearchResult = ds.FindAll();
    //to apply distinct on path property of elements in the collection
    var uniqueSearchResultsForPath =  overallSearchResult.Cast<System.DirectoryServices.SearchResult>().Select(x => x.Path).Distinct();

    //To apply distinct on any specific property in the "Properties" property of the elements in the collection
    //this will give you list of distinct departments for example

    var uniqueSearchResultsForDepartment = overallSearchResult.Cast<System.DirectoryServices.SearchResult>().Select(x => x.Properties["department"][0]).Distinct();
}
```

You will have to include `using System.Linq;` namespace in your C# file where you write this code.

Comment: still getting dupliate results

Comment: You want distinct results on which property? You can fetch a property on the objects in the collection and apply distinct on it. I've updated my code. It will give you distinct values of `path` property.

Comment: I've added some sample predicates which you can apply in `Select` clause of the LINQ query to apply distinctness on specific property of the objects in the collection.